# How to upload files to an Azure Batch auto storage via Azure Batch SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-batch, azure-sdk

It seems the Azure Batch SDK only supports downloading of blobs from the linked storage account via `ResourceFile.FromAutoStorageContainer(...)`. However, I couldn't find an easy way to upload files via the SDK.

Is there an *Azure-Batch-SDK-native* way to upload files to the link storage account (aka. auto storage)? Or do I really need `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` & `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` as suggested in this example [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/batch-dotnet-quickstart/blob/474d60f7c79c2bba15ab9ee29e68786bd58701c3/BatchDotnetQuickstart/Program.cs#L277).

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [OutputFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/task/add#outputfile) functionality to accomplish this. See the full [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-task-output-files) for more information.

Comment: Thx for replying. Unfortunately, I don't see how I can use OutputFiles for this task. Can you provide an example?